# How to tracking battery usage of apps running in android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying get power consumption value of apps running like on image below. [image]

How to track battery usage of apps running in android?

Comment: Google is your friend!SO is this other friend you call only when you have programming related questions

Answer (score 0):

There is a hidden API called BatteryStatsHelper which may help you get the power consumption values in mAh. There are two ways to get access to hidden api. One is use Java Reflection method. Another is to root the device and compile in source-code environment (https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api).

But the accuracy of battery consumption values highly depend on power_profile.xml preset by manufacture.